# Trouble with Figshpig WP Magento 1.9.1 Extension

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I have read trough all Fishpig problems, but none of the solutions work for me ;(

I have added the Fishpig extension and all works fins, BUT that the Store template is not being used. Basically all you see is the blog display only (not very ordered and nice - text should be centered).

I am stuck and do not know what can be causing this. Any ideas?
Site is:

http://www.malamujer.es/index.php/blognews

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a root template that doesn't include the header, sidebars and footer as these elements are not on this page what so ever.